# get first line in file via camel spliter and end splitter

Tags: apache-camel, splitter

I want to get first line of huge file. For this Im doing like

```
.tokenize("\n", 1).choice().when(simple("${property.CamelSplitIndex} == 0")).log("header month :: ${body}").endChoice()
```

with this Im getting first line, but the issue is here the splitter is continueing with other records also, this is effecting my waittime, cpu and memory. so, Any way i can read line one and end splitter without processing further lines.

appreciate the help.

Comment: I don't think you can do that in a splitter. You need to define a processor where you can add your code to extract the 1st line.

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this :

.tokenize("\n", 1).choice().when(simple("${property.CamelSplitIndex} == 0")).log("header month :: ${body}").setProperty("CamelSplitComplete", constant("true")).endChoice()

A little bit tricky but it could work with property CamelSplitComplete.